# Unconventional/underground philosophy

Tags: postmodernism

Are there any modern concepts of unconventional philosophy?

I endeavour to keep up with all modern books and scholars, yet I have no idea about "underground philosophy"?

Do you know something about it?

Maybe, are there any websites where people (students or professors) publish freely their philosophical works and thoughts?

Comment: There is no need for underground these days, everything is online. [Philosophers' Carnival](https://sites.google.com/site/tristanhaze/links-to-all-philosophers-carnival-editions), now transformed into [Philosophical Blog Posts](http://philblogposts.blogspot.com/), indexes posts on various philosophical blogs.